# How to push a nested object with SchemaType options to mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const VacancySchema = new Schema(
    {
        parameters: []
    },
    { timestamps: true },
    { strict: false }
);
      
module.exports = mongoose.model('Vacancy', VacancySchema);
```

I am trying to create a dynamic model in node.js using mongoose. The `parameters` field accepts a list of objects. These objects are nested javascript objects that contains some data and SchemaType options like `type, trim, required, etc.` that modify the content of the data. I want to insert these and similar fields to the `parameters` array in mongoose.

As you might have guessed, these fields are dynamic and I cannot save them in the model initially. Now the problem that I am facing is when I store these objects to the model, the options like `trim` loses their functionality i.e., they do not work. If I insert these options first, and then push the data, the fields get overwritten. What is the best approach to tackle this situation?

EDIT:

To insert the data:

```js
await Vacancy.create({
      parameters: paramArray,
      template: "some id",
      status: 0
  });
```

User input:

```js
{
  client: "  ABC  ",
  name: " XYZ   ",
}
```

The object I have stored as json:

```js
paramArray: [
  client: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    section: 0
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    section: 0
  }
]
```

Expected result:

Output in db: (The user data gets stored in the db and the trim operation gets applied to the data)

```js
parameters: [{
    client: "ABC"
  },
  {
    name: "XYZ"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you include example documents?

Comment: I have added the statement I am using to add the document. Do you want anything else?

Comment: You declare parameters as an Array, but you passed paramsArray object. Do you mean to pass multiple of objects in the same shape?

Comment: I still don't quite get what you try to achieve. You might need to give more examples of how it should behave with specific sample data and operations.

Comment: In your param array, you specified that `client` is required, but in `parameters` the second object doesn't have `client` field

Comment: Do you want to keep `trim`, `required`, `section` inside the database? Or just in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your Mongoose schema syntax is wrong. I corrected as;

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const VacancySchema = new Schema({
  parameters: [],
  timestamps: true,
  strict: false
});

const Vacancy = model('Vacancy', VacancySchema);

module.exports = Vacancy;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but there is no problem with the one I used either.